# How do I add parameter to html object tag?

Tags: html, pdf, tags

Here is the code:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="ajax/test/pdf-export.php?uid=" height = 600px width = 600px></object>
```

I need to add unique uid (userID) to the URL, but I don't know how to do it. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
<object 
    type="application/pdf" 
    data="ajax/test/pdf-export.php?uid=someuid" 
    height="600px"
    width="600px">
</object>
```

The `someid` is whatever if you want to use, it has to be encoded by something like `urlencode()`, depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on technology you're using. If it's php, you do

`$userID = 'somestring';
echo "<object type=\"application/pdf\" data=\"ajax/test/pdf-export.php?uid=$userID\" height = \"600px\" width = \"600px\"></object>";`

If it's javascript:

`var userID = '222';
document.write("<object type='application/pdf' data='ajax/test/pdf-export.php?uid=" + userID + " height = '600px' width = '600px'></object>");`
`